# SharePoint Document Folders Not Accessible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, folder, token, directory

I apologize if this question is dealt with elsewhere, but so far I haven't been able to locate it.

My company is running SharePoint Server 2007. I am an `owner/admin` of several sites and they all experience the same phenomenon: after a period, a given folder is no longer accessible to a user whose permissions are properly set up, has been able to access the folder before, and can actually view the site.

This manifests in certain VBA routines that I've written in Excel that save or retrieve files from these folders and in shortcuts created on my desktop that link directly to the document folder.

The error that appears is

> "The drive or network connection that the shortcut XXX.lnk refers to
>   is unavailable." for shortcuts and "The path '\xxxx\xxx\' does not
>   exist or is not a directory." in VBA routines.

The workaround that I've been giving to users is to copy the direct folder path, hit Start > Run, paste in the folder path, and click OK. This pulls up a request for the user's name and password and they're once again able to pull / save files to the folder again.

Can someone explain why this happens so that I can either code around it or explain to my SharePoint team how to fix it? Is it related to tokens?